# Minimizing the size of PDF files

Tags: windows, pdf, minimization

Minimizing the size of JavaScript code (like [JS Minifier](https://javascript-minifier.com/)) or PNGs (like [Tiny PNG](https://tinypng.com/)) are meant to reduce the bandwidth and speedup loading times of websites.

I'm looking for a similar thing but for PDF files. For testing purposes (in unit tests if that matters) I need PDFs which are small.

- the operation should be lossless by default
- minimizing may remove embedded fonts and assume they are present on the system
- minimizing may change the PDF version
- it should provide an option to resize images (no longer lossless)

The tool needs to work on Windows and cost less than 10 EUR or 10 USD.

Answer (score 0):

You could use online PDF compressors such as [I love PDFs](https://www.ilovepdf.com/compress_pdf) which worked for me.

It reduced one of my PDFs from 557 MB to 89 MB.

Answer (score 0):

[Free PDF Compressor](http://www.freepdfcompressor.com/) could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[GhostScript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) could work, it has a bunch of different options. It's a powerful but perhaps not too easy to use tool. There are however many examples of usage around the web, e.g.:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450120/optimize-pdf-files-with-ghostscript-or-other
https://askubuntu.com/questions/113544/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-scanned-pdf-file